# matplotlib hammer projection draw outside map

Tags: matplotlib, axes

I found a figure with a hammer projection which I've been trying to replicate.
The Hammer projection itself is not a problem, but I don't know how to produce the axis below the map. In fact, I have no clue as to how to draw (arrows and text) something outside of the figure. Can anyone help with an idea how to replicate the figure with the axis on the bottom?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use annotations (see http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html) in figure coordinates (pixels or fraction)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `transform` keyword to plot things in axes-coordinates instead of data-coordinates. If you have constructed an axes-object `ax` ([see here](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes)) to plot e.g. the lower left text string "180°"  you could use

```
ax.text(0, 0, '180$^\circ$', ha='left', transform=ax.transAxes)
```

`transform=ax.transAxes`  sets the coordinate system so that the point `(0, 0)` is at the bottom left, `(1, 0)` at the bottom right, `(1, 1)` at the top right, and `(0, 1)` at the top left, regardless of which values the axes spans in data-coordinates.

To draw the arrows you can equivalently use [`ax.arrow`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.arrow), also with the `transform` keyword.

Comment: I tried your suggested solution but it looks like there is no enough room below the map to draw the arrows and text. The arrow head looks cut-off plus if extend it to the middle bottom of the map it will actually overlap with the map itself. Here is the code: 

`fig = plt.figure()
rect = 0.05,0.05,0.9,0.9
ax = fig.add_axes(rect)
m = Basemap(projection='hammer',lon_0=0,resolution='c')
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,120.,30.))
ax.text(0, 0, '180$^\circ$', ha='left', transform=ax.transAxes)
ax.arrow(0.05, 0.0, 0.1, 0, head_width=0.05, head_length=0.05, fc='k', ec='k',transform=ax.transAxes)`

Comment: Try to make the axes smaller with respect to the figure, e.g.  `ax=fig.add_axes([0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 0.6])` gives you 1/5 (=0.2) of your figure size of whitespace at each side of the axis. This should give you plenty of space for your sidenotes.

Comment: thank you for trying to help me, but it still does not work. The arrow is still cut-off. My code, according to your suggestions is:
`from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.2,0.2,0.6,0.6])

m = Basemap(projection='hammer',lon_0=0,resolution='c')
# draw parallels and meridians.
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,120.,30.))
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(0.,420.,60.))
ax1.arrow(0, 0, 0.5, 0, head_width=0.05, head_length=0.05, fc='k', ec='k',transform=ax1.transAxes)
plt.show()`

can you try that to see?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the `mpl_toolkits.basemap` installed and will not. I dont see, how you relate the `Basemap` to the `ax1`. Maybe look for some keyword arguments in the `Basemap` documentation to explicitly plot it on `ax`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, building on the above:

I've used radians to label my axes and am using a polar coordinate system, but the principle is the same:

```
# custom x-axis
ax.text(.49, -.15, '0', ha='left', transform=ax.transAxes)
ax.text(.24, -.15, r'$\frac{\pi}{2}$', ha='left', transform=ax.transAxes)
ax.text(0, -.15, r"$\pi$", ha='left', transform=ax.transAxes)
ax.text(.74, -.15, r"$\frac{3\pi}{2}$", ha='left', transform=ax.transAxes)
ax.text(.98, -.15, r"$\pi$", ha='left', transform=ax.transAxes)

ax.annotate('', xy=(.96, -.1275), xycoords='axes fraction', xytext=(.78, -.1275), 
        arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="<-", alpha=.35))
ax.annotate('', xy=(.72, -.1275), xycoords='axes fraction', xytext=(.52, -.1275), 
        arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="<-", alpha=.35))
ax.annotate('', xy=(.48, -.1275), xycoords='axes fraction', xytext=(.27, -.1275), 
        arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="<-", alpha=.35))
ax.annotate('', xy=(.23, -.1275), xycoords='axes fraction', xytext=(.03, -.1275), 
        arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="<-", alpha=.35))


# custom y-axis
ax.text(.84, .98, '0', ha='left', transform=ax.transAxes)
ax.text(.84, -.03, r"$\pi$", ha='left', transform=ax.transAxes)

ax.annotate('', xy=(.85, .12), xycoords='axes fraction', xytext=(.85, .01), 
        arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="<-", alpha=.35))
ax.annotate('', xy=(.851, .97), xycoords='axes fraction', xytext=(.851, .87), 
        arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-", alpha=.35))
```

[Output plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxT93.png)